# Galois group of degree 7 polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

From Bosch‘s Algebra (p. 368):

> Determine the galois group of $$X^7 - 8X^5 - 4X^4 + 2X^3 - 4X^2 + 2 \in \mathbb Q[X]$$ and decide if it‘s solvable or not.

How does one find the galois group of that polynomial?

My usual way is to find the roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, find a splitting field $L = L(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ and then study the structure of the galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q) = \operatorname{Gal}(f)$ as a subgroup of $S_n$.

However that does not seem to work in this case since already finding roots seems difficult. What is a useful approach in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

1. Use [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) to show that $f$ is irreducible.
2. Show that $f$ has exactly $5$ real roots. (Since $f$ has negative discriminant, $f$ has either exactly $1$ or exactly $5$ real roots, hence it suffices to show that $f$ has at least $2$ real roots.)

What kind of permutations do (1), (2) (separately) imply occur in $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$?

> 1. So, $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ contains a $7$-cycle.

> 2. Complex conjugation exchanges the $2$ nonreal roots of $f$, hence it determines a transposition in $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$.

Comment: Thank you! Why does (1) imply that $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ contains a $7$-cycle? But then, since the Galois group contains a $7$-cycle and a transposition, it is $S_7$, right?

Comment: @ATW By Cauchy's theorem, it is sufficient to show that the order of $\text{Gal}(f)$ is divisible by $7$. Show this by using irreducibility.

Comment: Like that? Since $f$ is irreducible and $\operatorname{char} \mathbb Q = 0$, $f$ is separable, hence $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \subseteq S_7$ is a subgroup and by Lagrange, $|\operatorname{Gal}(f)| \mid |S_7| = 7!$ - okay, but why does $7 \mid |\operatorname{Gal}(f)|$ hold?

Comment: @ATW The Galois group has an element of order $7$, namely a $7$-cycle, and the subgroup generated by it has order $7$ and divides the group order by Lagrange.

Comment: @ATW Take any root $\alpha$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a subfield of the splitting field. What is $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$?

Comment: @Mark Since $\alpha$ is a root of $f \in \mathbb Q[X]$, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is algebraic, so if $m \in \mathbb Q[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $[\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] = \operatorname{deg}(m) \mid \operatorname{deg f} = 7$.

Comment: @ATW Since $f$ is irreducible, it itself must be the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Ah, and since $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is an intermediate field, $7 = [\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] \mid |\operatorname{Gal}(f)$. Thanks!

Comment: @ATW I'm late to the party, but yes, a $7$-cycle and a transposition generate all of $S_7$.